# Pandas count number of online devices at a time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes which is a log database which shows each time a device connects to a new gateway

| device | gateway | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 1 | 2021-01-01 05:02:03 |
| 222 | 2 | 2021-01-02 06:02:04 |
| 222 | 1 | 2021-01-03 02:02:53 |
| 223 | 3 | 2021-01-01 01:22:08 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 222 | 1 | 2021-02-01 12:32:23 |

I want to know for each minute for all the gateways how many devices are currently connected to each of the gateways

| gateway | minute | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:01:00 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 05:02:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 05:03:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 05:04:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 05:05:00 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 06:02:00 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

how can I accomplish this using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Try `groupby` with `Grouper`:

```
df.groupby(['gateway', pd.Grouper(freq='T', key='time')]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: But doesn't this only count the number of devices that switched to this gateway in this minute? I also want to know how many switched to this gateway earlier and didn't switch to another one yet. Ill add details in the question

Comment: Sounds like a `pd.crosstab` and then `unstack`. Still, you should include the expected outcome **from** the sample data. I'll be deleting this answer in few minutes.